# How to insert boilerplate code in a file based on the directory in which it is created?

Tags: files, skeleton

Suppose I have a file `dir1/this_file.txt` and `dir2/this_file.txt`, and I want to insert different boilerplate code not based on the file name or extension, but based on the directory in which the file is created. How can I do that?

-- Edit --

Additionally, what if the boilerplate code depends on the filename of the file being created?

Comment: If my answer answers your Q, please consider tagging it as the Answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As phils said obtain the directory name

```
(file-name-directory (or buffer-file-name ""))
```

and then open a boilerplate template in that directory is maybe what you want rather than configure the template code in Emacs itself.  I knocked this up and it seems to work.

```
  (defun insert-boilerplate ()
    (let ((boiler-plate-file (expand-file-name ".boilerplate" (file-name-directory (or buffer-file-name "")))))
      (if (file-exists-p boiler-plate-file)
          (insert-file-contents boiler-plate-file)))
    nil)
  (add-to-list 'find-file-not-found-functions #'insert-boilerplate)
```

Simply create a .boilerplate file in the directory and it should be good to go.

Comment: thanks. Always welcome. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Or just use `(if (file-exists-p ".boilerplate") (insert-file-contents ".boilerplate"))` which will do the same.

Comment: Heh. Indeed. It includes the full path. Noted.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the directory with:

```
(file-name-directory (or buffer-file-name ""))
```

Comment: You can also just use `default-directory` which will not *always* be identical, but for all practical purposes it is.

Comment: Heh.  Yes, I obviously had a bit of a brain-fade there...